# to trim spaces an \n from NSString

Tags: iphone, nsstring

I have `NSString   @" (\n  "Bi_ss"   \n) "`
I want to get String   `@"Bi_ss "`

Any one has any idea about this ?
Thank you

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
NSString *trimmedString = [string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:
                                  [NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
```

From [Cocoanetics](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2009/01/remove-whitespace-from-nsstring/)...

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at the `NSString` method `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString` for example, this should be able to perform the basic task you want it to do.